# In my web app, MacOS messes up my formatting while windows treats it fine

Tags: html, css

I am building a web app that requires me to use a bunch of lines (which I did using divs and adding css). I am trying to get this app to work on macOS, but the formatting is all off and the lines are not aligning. How should I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help?

Comment: I actually figured it out... I wasn't positioning the divs relative to each other so it was screwing up

Comment: It's would still be nice to share what your question was and what you found as a solution for the rest of us

Answer (score 0):

Solved It: I used vw instead of px.